# How many binary strings of length $10$ contain at least $4$ $0$'s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm not sure how do deal with the at least part. The way I understand it is that I have to the opposite, so find all the number of ways that there's no zero, $1$ zero, $2$ zeros, and $3$ zeros.

Attempt:

$2^{10} - (10C1) - (10C2) - (10C3) - 1$

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Looks good to me.